# Ionic App can't build on Android AAPT Error

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework

I am creating a Ionic App, emulating it in Browser works fine, but as soon as i try to build it on android it fails. Looks like some error with AATP, but i cant realy figure out, why this happens... 
 Here is the Error Log:

```
Running app-scripts build: --platform android --target cordova
[00:03:39]  build dev started ... 
[00:03:39]  clean started ... 
[00:03:39]  clean finished in 36 ms 
[00:03:39]  copy started ... 
[00:03:39]  deeplinks started ... 
[00:03:39]  deeplinks finished in 46 ms 
[00:03:39]  transpile started ... 
[00:03:43]  transpile finished in 4.22 s 
[00:03:43]  preprocess started ... 
[00:03:43]  preprocess finished in 1 ms 
[00:03:43]  webpack started ... 
[00:03:43]  copy finished in 4.49 s 
[00:03:50]  webpack finished in 6.46 s 
[00:03:50]  sass started ... 
Without `from` option PostCSS could generate wrong source map and will not find Browserslist config. Set it to CSS file path or to `undefined` to prevent this warning.
[00:03:51]  sass finished in 942 ms 
[00:03:51]  postprocess started ... 
[00:03:51]  postprocess finished in 14 ms 
[00:03:51]  lint started ... 
[00:03:51]  build dev finished in 11.87 s 
> cordova run android
Android Studio project detected
ANDROID_HOME=E:\AndroidSDK
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161
studio
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
publishNonDefault is deprecated and has no effect anymore. All variants are now published.
Configuration 'compile' in project ':app' is deprecated. Use 'implementation' instead.
The Task.leftShift(Closure) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use Task.doLast(Action) instead.
    at build_c6trj2zw0ratkgf1y8h09dz0v.run(C:\Users\Sebastian\Google Drive\GIT\myepa_mobile\platforms\android\app\build.gradle:144)
[00:03:56]  tslint: C:/Users/Sebastian/Google Drive/GIT/myepa_mobile/src/pages/scanner/scanner.ts, line: 24 
            Property 'alertCtrl' is declared but never used. 

      L23:  private qrScanner: BarcodeScanner,
      L24:  private alertCtrl: AlertController,
      L25:  private storage: StorageProvider,

            Property 'storage' is declared but never used. 

      L24:  private alertCtrl: AlertController,
      L25:  private storage: StorageProvider,
      L26:  private api: ApiProvider,

            All imports are unused. 

       L2:  //import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
       L3:  i[00:03:56]  tslint: C:/Users/Sebastian/Google Drive/GIT/myepa_mobile/src/pages/scanner/scanner.ts, line: 25 
[00:03:56]  tslint: ...bastian/Google Drive/GIT/myepa_mobile/src/pages/medicationplan/medicationplan.ts, line: 3 
[00:03:56]  tslint: C:/Users/Sebastian/Google Drive/GIT/myepa_mobile/src/pages/settings/settings.ts, line: 13 
[00:03:56]  tslint: C:/Users/Sebastian/Google Drive/GIT/myepa_mobile/src/pages/docs/docs.ts, line: 18 
[00:03:56]  tslint: C:/Users/Sebastian/Google Drive/GIT/myepa_mobile/src/pages/docs/docs.ts, line: 21 
mport {BarcodeScanner, BarcodeScannerOptions} from "@ionic-native/barcode-scanner";
       L4:  //import {StorageProvider} from "../../providers/storage/storage";

            Property 'navParams' is declared but never used. 

      L12:  constructor(private navCtrl: NavController,
      L13:              private navParams: NavParams,
      L14:              private storage: StorageProvider,

            Property 'navParams' is declared but never used. 

      L17:  constructor(private navCtrl: NavController,
      L18:              private navParams: NavParams,
      L19:              private api: ApiProvider,

            Property 'zone' is declared but never used. 

      L20:            private events: Events,
      L21:            private zone: NgZone) {
      L22:  events.subscribe("res:update", () =>{

[00:03:56]  lint finished in 5.12 s 
:CordovaLib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:platformAttrExtractor UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
:CordovaLib:transformClassesAndResourcesWithPrepareIntermediateJarsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:splitsDiscoveryTaskDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResourcesC:\Users\Sebastian\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-compat-28.0.0-alpha1.aar\87f8372badb42114e191aeebff73693e\res\values\values.xml:20:5-70: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.

C:\Users\Sebastian\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-compat-28.0.0-alpha1.aar\87f8372badb42114e191aeebff73693e\res\values\values.xml:20:5-70: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.

C:\Users\Sebastian\Google Drive\GIT\myepa_mobile\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:141: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
C:\Users\Sebastian\Google Drive\GIT\myepa_mobile\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:141: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
error: failed linking references.

Failed to execute aapt
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:796)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.invokeAaptForSplit(ProcessAndroidResources.java:551)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.doFullTaskAction(ProcessAndroidResources.java:285)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:109)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:173)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:121)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:122)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:111)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:63)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248) FAILED
25 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 24 up-to-date

    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:124)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:80)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:105)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:625)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:580)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:503)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:482)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:79)
    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:794)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:503)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:462)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:79)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.QueueableAapt2.lambda$makeValidatedPackage$1(QueueableAapt2.java:179)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$NotifierProcessOutput.handleOutput(AaptProcess.java:454)
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$NotifierProcessOutput.err(AaptProcess.java:411)
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$ProcessOutputFacade.err(AaptProcess.java:332)
    at com.android.utils.GrabProcessOutput$1.run(GrabProcessOutput.java:104)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Failed to execute aapt

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
(node:14708) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
C:\Users\Sebastian\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-compat-28.0.0-alpha1.aar\87f8372badb42114e191aeebff73693e\res\values\values.xml:20:5-70: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.

C:\Users\Sebastian\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-compat-28.0.0-alpha1.aar\87f8372badb42114e191aeebff73693e\res\values\values.xml:20:5-70: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.

C:\Users\Sebastian\Google Drive\GIT\myepa_mobile\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:141: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
C:\Users\Sebastian\Google Drive\GIT\myepa_mobile\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:141: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
error: failed linking references.

Failed to execute aapt
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:796)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.invokeAaptForSplit(ProcessAndroidResources.java:551)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.doFullTaskAction(ProcessAndroidResources.java:285)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:109)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:173)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:121)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:122)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:111)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:63)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:124)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:80)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:105)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:625)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:580)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:503)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:482)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:79)
    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:794)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:503)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:462)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:79)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.QueueableAapt2.lambda$makeValidatedPackage$1(QueueableAapt2.java:179)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$NotifierProcessOutput.handleOutput(AaptProcess.java:454)
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$NotifierProcessOutput.err(AaptProcess.java:411)
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$ProcessOutputFacade.err(AaptProcess.java:332)
    at com.android.utils.GrabProcessOutput$1.run(GrabProcessOutput.java:104)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Failed to execute aapt

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
(node:14708) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

[OK] Your app has been deployed.
     Did you know you can live-reload changes from your app with --livereload?
```

I cant really fiqure out, what happend, because early this day building the app worked fine...

My Ionic Project Enviroment Info:

```
cli packages: (C:\Users\Sebastian\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.1
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.1

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8
    Cordova Platforms  : android 7.0.0 browser 5.0.3
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:

    Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
    Node              : v8.9.4
    npm               : 5.6.0
    OS                : Windows 10

Environment Variables:

    ANDROID_HOME : E:\AndroidSDK

Misc:

    backend : pro
```

EDIT: 
I solved the Problem by deinstalling all plugins an installing them one by one. 
The plugin BarcodeScanner was the problem ([here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/barcode-scanner/)). Changing the value `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'` to `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23+'`  in the starter-barcodescanner.gradle file under platforms/android/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner resolved the problem.

Comment: I have the same issue, as of today. I also noticed that if I remove the `cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation` all builds and deploys fine.

Comment: Same issue here, also starting in the past 24 hours.  iOS builds are fine.  Nothing has changed in the build env I'm aware of in the past 3 days other than a java system update.  Identical `ionic info` as OP, except for: 


    global:
    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.0.1 
    
    local packages:
    @ionic/app-scripts : 1.3.6
    Cordova Platforms  : .idea android 6.4.0 ios 4.4.0
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 2.2.0
    
    System:
    ios-deploy : 1.9.2 
    ios-sim    : 6.0.0 
    Node       : v8.4.0
    npm        : 2.15.12 
    OS         : macOS Sierra

Comment: Same. Seemingly out of the blue without making any updates to my dev environment at all. Leads me to believe that there is a dependency update under the covers that has hosed the Android build. Funny thing is, I have another machine that is building fine.

Comment: Same here. Just started happening today. I systematically removed each of my plugins and it did not fix it. Once I removed all of them and removed and added the platform then the build worked. I tried removing and adding the platform and adding all the plugins back in and it still does not work.

Answer (score 24):

Some plugins may encounter incompatibilities due to new updates of Android Support Libraries as explained in other replies here.

Easiest fix is by installing "**cordova-android-support-gradle-release**" plugin. This plugin will automatically align the version of the plugin which crashed and you **can continue to use your plugin**.

Also this fix **is persistent** compared with manually change the version directly into the plugin.

```
cordova plugin add cordova-android-support-gradle-release --fetch
```

Also you may have a look into the [documentation](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-android-support-gradle-release) and other related issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49200782/4423449)

Comment: I got `dialogCornerRadius not found` after adding `phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner v8.1.0` to `Cordova Android 7.1.4` project with `Cordova v8.1.1` (OS: Ubuntu 18.04). Above fixed my issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot Andrew. Saved me possibly many hours of debugging!

Answer (score 4):

This build failure is due to a major version release of the Google Play Services and Firebase libaries on June 17.

Worked for me

Run:

1. `ionic cordova platform rm android`
2. if your using firebase

   ```
   cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-firebase

   cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase-lib
   ```
3. Run:

`ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-androidx`

4. Run:

`ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter`

5. Run:

   `ionic cordova platform add android@8.0.0`

Enjoy with your apk

`ionic cordova build android --prod --release`

Answer (score -1):

I found my answer here:

[Build Error -Ionic Cordova fails for android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49163472/build-error-ionic-cordova-fails-for-android)

Also, mine required a similar fix as above only it was in the de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification plugin. I changed ‘com.android.support:support-v4:+’ to ‘com.android.support:support-v4:23+’ and then removed and added the android platform and it built. However, I had an extra brace '}' in my build-extras.gradle that had to be removed also.

Answer (score -1):

I can verify the gradle-plugin fixed it.
Tried the support-version numbers before but the plugin was the only thing that solved it for me after 3 weeks of debugging!