# Ionic ERROR: In <declare-styleable> FontFamilyFont, unable to find attribute android:fontVariationSettings

Tags: android, ionic-framework

When I run

> ionic cordova build android --prod

it shows errors below:

```
    ERROR: In <declare-styleable> FontFamilyFont, unable to find attribute android:fontVariationSettings
ERROR: In <declare-styleable> FontFamilyFont, unable to find attribute android:ttcIndex

    FAILED

    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
    > com.android.ide

.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

* Try:

Run with 
--stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED


Total time: 9.11 secs

Error: /Users/cqismgis/Desktop/MobileGIS/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
注: 某些输入文件使用或覆盖了已过时的 API。
注: 有关详细信息, 请使用 -Xlint:deprecation 重新编译。
注: 某些输入文件使用或覆盖了已过时的 API。
注: 有关详细信息, 请使用 -Xlint:deprecation 重新编译。
ERROR: In <declare-styleable> FontFamilyFont, unable to find attribute android:fontVariationSettings
ERROR: In <declare-styleable> FontFamilyFont, unable to find attribute android:ttcIndex


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

and in AndroidStudio, I clikc 'Build' button, it shows:

```
    Error:In <declare-styleable> FontFamilyFont, unable to find attribute android:fontVariationSettings
    Error:Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
```

I don't know how to fix it, please tell me the detail of fix steps.

Comment: Try updating your compileSdkVersion to 28.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49162538/running-cordova-build-android-unable-to-find-attribute-androidfontvariation Following the answer and then fix this problem

Answer (score 33, accepted):

To solve that :

> you_app_folder/plugin and look for plugin.xml in all the plugins

Go to your plugin folder, search in that directory for :

```
com.android.support:support-v4:+
```

OR

```
com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1+
```

OR

```
com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0
```

Change it with :

```
com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0
```

OR

```
com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1
```

then

Also, I executed

```
ionic cordova platform remove android
```

and

```
ionic cordova platform add android
```

Comment: Hi, can you please tell me where exactly I've to go and change the version?

Comment: @ShihanKhan you_app_folder/plugin and look for plugin.xml in all the plugins

Comment: I had the same problem and changing from `com.android.support:support-v4:+` to compile `com.android.support:support-v4:23.+` fixed it for me.

Comment: Thanks , works great

Comment: I fixed it by editing `platforms/android/build.gradle` according to https://github.com/crosswalk-project/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview/issues/205#issuecomment-371669478

Comment: Added this to `build-extras.gradle`

    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force 'com.android.support:support-v4:26+'
        }
    }


Found info at - https://github.com/crosswalk-project/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview/issues/205#issuecomment-371669478

Comment: @nanusdad this is an option to change only the module you want to upgrade, not all of them