# react native failed to execute aapt

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

I have an old react native app which has stopped building after updating my Mac

the error after react-native run-android is, I have no clue what could be the problem. Can anyone help me?

```
...

:react-native-device-info:compileReleaseRenderscript

:react-native-device-info:generateReleaseBuildConfig

:react-native-device-info:generateReleaseResValues

:react-native-device-info:generateReleaseResources

:react-native-device-info:mergeReleaseResources

:react-native-device-info:processReleaseManifest

:react-native-device-info:processReleaseResources

ERROR: In <declare-styleable> FontFamilyFont, unable to find attribute android:font

ERROR: In <declare-styleable> FontFamilyFont, unable to find attribute android:fontStyle

ERROR: In <declare-styleable> FontFamilyFont, unable to find attribute android:fontVariationSettings

ERROR: In <declare-styleable> FontFamilyFont, unable to find attribute android:fontWeight

ERROR: In <declare-styleable> FontFamilyFont, unable to find attribute android:ttcIndex

ERROR: In <declare-styleable> GradientColor, unable to find attribute android:endX

ERROR: In <declare-styleable> GradientColor, unable to find attribute android:endY

ERROR: In <declare-styleable> GradientColor, unable to find attribute android:startX

ERROR: In <declare-styleable> GradientColor, unable to find attribute android:startY

ERROR: In <declare-styleable> GradientColorItem, unable to find attribute android:offset

:react-native-device-info:processReleaseResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-device-info:processReleaseResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
```

my build.gradle has

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "**********"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 10
        versionName "1.10"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49192174/1848929

Comment: https://github.com/mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation/issues/116#issuecomment-346899100

Comment: @hakiko your link is about Cordova not react-native