# Ionic - Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at ‘dialogCornerRadius’ with value ‘?android:attr/dialogCornerRadius’)

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

Morning it was working fine, but when I made a build it downloaded something and throwing this error.

```
Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at ‘dialogCornerRadius’ with value ‘?android:attr/dialogCornerRadius’)
```

Is this because of Android P in the market?

INFO
     @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.1
        ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.1

```
global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 2.1.3
    Cordova Platforms  : android 6.3.0
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.6.0

System:

    Android SDK Tools : 26.0.2
    Node              : v7.8.0
    npm               : 4.2.0
    OS                : Windows 10

Environment Variables:

    ANDROID_HOME : C:\Users\dell2\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running "cordova build android" - unable to find attribute android:fontVariationSettings and android:ttcIndex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49162538/running-cordova-build-android-unable-to-find-attribute-androidfontvariation)

Answer (score 2):

Try install plugin [cordova-android-support-gradle-release](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-android-support-gradle-release).

RUN: `cordova plugin add cordova-android-support-gradle-release`

After install succeed, run `ionic cordova build android`, will build successful.

Reference: [Ionic Forum](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/error-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-at-dialogcornerradius-with-value-android-attr-dialogcornerradius/124069/5?u=ionic_yuyang)