# Project sync failed After adding Google places API

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services, google-places-api

i Want to add new google places api to my existing project but it gives error project sync error

I have added implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.1.0' to project

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false // Add this
        abortOnError false
    }
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
            storeFile file('***')
            storePassword 'android'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "888"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 47
        versionName "2.8"
        testInstrumentationRunner 
  "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

```
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.0-native'
implementation 'io.branch.sdk.android:library:2.+'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
implementation 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:0.7@aar'
implementation 'net.gotev:uploadservice:2.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.11.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko:$anko_version"
implementation 'us.belka:androidtoggleswitch:1.2.2'
implementation 'com.daimajia.easing:library:2.0@aar'
implementation 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:2.3@aar'
implementation 'net.gotev:uploadservice:3.4.2'
implementation 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4'
implementation 'net.gotev:uploadservice-okhttp:3.4.2'
implementation 'cn.jzvd:jiaozivideoplayer:6.3.1'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
implementation 'id.zelory:compressor:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.github.WindSekirun.NaraeAudioRecorder:core:1.1.0'
implementation('com.paytm:pgplussdk:1.3.1') {
    transitive = true
}
```

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

it shows me error

The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-base is being requested by various other libraries at [[15.0.1,15.0.1]], but resolves to 16.1.0. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.

Comment: I think your firebase dependencies uses com.google.android.gms:play-services-base version 16.1.0 but rest of the dependencies like maps,places uses a lower version 15.0.1, so you must update the map,place etc to a version with uses com.google.android.gms:play-services-base 16.1.0

Comment: after removing firebase auth dependency project synced successfully but after that i am getting this error ... error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found. error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.    ......... can you please tell me what is the issue

Comment: try changing compileSdkVersion to version 28, please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49208772/error-resource-androidattr-fontvariationsettings-not-found

Comment: Could not find com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1.
Required by:
    project :app > com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.4.0