# build flutter com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource linking failed

Tags: android, flutter, dart

yesterday, I upgraded flutter to the latest version(1.12.13+hotfix.5),i got the following errors when building the flutter apk

```
* What went wrong:                                                                                                 
Execution failed for task ':sharesdk_plugin:verifyReleaseResources'.                                               
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource linking failed
  /Users/binaryiv/Documents/projects/appProjects/huoli/app/build/sharesdk_plugin/intermediates/res/merged/release/values/values.xml:879: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
  /Users/binaryiv/Documents/projects/appProjects/huoli/app/build/sharesdk_plugin/intermediates/res/merged/release/values/values.xml:880: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
  error: failed linking references.
```

my compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion is 28,i can build it by deleting the `sharesdk_plugin` plugin. Is there any other way to configure and keep the plugin by building

Answer (score 4):

I found in the [error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49208772/error-resource-androidattr-fontvariationsettings-not-found) last answer can solved my problems with sharesdk_plugin Add the code:

```
subprojects {
    afterEvaluate {project ->
        if (project.hasProperty("android")) {
            android {
                compileSdkVersion 28
                buildToolsVersion '29.0.2'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

in android/build.gradle in the last.
Good luck for you.

Comment: i was able to fix such an issue by just doing the change for a specific project `...if (project.name == "plugin_that_has_the_issue") { android { .... } }`

Answer (score 2):

go to the file:

```
~/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sharesdk_plugin-1.2.1/android/build.gradle
```

and change **all** compileSdkVersion to:

```
compileSdkVersion 28
```

ps:
There may be more than 1 compileSdkVersion in build.gradle.

Answer (score 1):

I also had same issue but the plugin was different.
Firstly remove cache i.e Invalidate cache/restart then, 
add:
android.enableAapt2=false in gradle.properties.