# Android release apk commond not working in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.Please give suggestion what to do to overcome errors.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':connectivity:verifyReleaseResources'.

  > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
  >   Android resource linking failed
  >    /Users/admin/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/45a69bab8db1875a48488dcfd567eca0/core-1.0.0/res/values/values.xml:57:5-88:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.

While executing flutter build apk --release commons it throws below errors:

> /Users/admin/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/45a69bab8db1875a48488dcfd567eca0/core-1.0.0/res/values/values.xml:57:5-88:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49208772/error-resource-androidattr-fontvariationsettings-not-found)

Comment: No.@MartinZeitler

Comment: try flutter clean command in your terminal and then build your project