# Ionic 3 AAPT error after gradle update: resource fontVariationSettings not found

Tags: android, ionic-framework, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, ionic3

The problem is that since this morning (I believe, I have not worked yesterday) when I try to run my ionic 3 application on the device I get an **AAPT error.**

To recreate the problem I started from a scratch app.

I create a simple new ionic application:

```
ionic start gradleError tabs
```

Now if I try to run it on my device it works

Let's say I want to add [this plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/background-geolocation/) using simply this two commands:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation
npm install --save @ionic-native/background-geolocation
```

Now when I try to run it on my device I get the following Errors:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Failed to execute aapt
```

Reading the error output is seems that the problem is this one:

```
fontVariationSettings not found.

ttcIndex not found.
```

First fix attempt was made by changing inside "platforms/android/project.properties" the line into:

```
cordova.system.library.2=com.android.support:support-v4:26+
```

After trying to run in on device I start to get a bunch of errors which looks like:

```
    /Users/zeno/Desktop/Bachelor/App/gradleError/test/platforms/android/app/src/main/java/com/tenforwardconsulting/cordova/BackgroundGeolocationPlugin.java:563: error: cannot find symbol

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
                                  ^
  symbol:   variable KITKAT
  location: class VERSION_CODES
/Users/zeno/Desktop/Bachelor/App/gradleError/test/platforms/android/app/src/main/java/org/apache/cordova/splashscreen/SplashScreen.java:297: error: cannot find symbol

                LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                                                                                      ^
  symbol:   variable MATCH_PARENT
```

With ate the end:

> ```
>     * What went wrong:
> Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> ```

Now following what has been said [on the ionic forum](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/android-build-broken-after-gradle-dependencies-update-execution-failed-for-task-processdebugresources-com-android-ide-common-process-processexception-failed-to-execute-aapt/109982/155) I tried to run the following command:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-android-support-gradle-release --variable ANDROID_SUPPORT_VERSION=27.0.0
```

with which I get the same errors as the change I made before.

I tried also to play with the system and the numbers, from 27 to 27.1 to 24 and so on, nothing changed.

Comment: Might be related to https://stackoverflow.com/q/49162538/5730444. Maybe try if adding a build-extras.gradle fixes this issue

Comment: Sorry for the very late reply.
No I tried all the solutions in that post and nothing worked.
I tracked down the problem beign https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/background-geolocation/ this plugin

The problem now seems to be this: /Users/zeno/Desktop/Bachelor/Ionic/ticaccio/platforms/android/app/src/main/java/com/tenforwardconsulting/cordova/BackgroundGeolocationPlugin.java:563: error: cannot find symbol

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)