# Cordova build to Android error

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio, construct

I made an app with Construct 2 and I exported to Intel XDK. Then I exported to cordova and everytime I try to build with "cordova build android" I get this error:

ERROR: In  FontFamilyFont, unable to find attribute android:t
tcIndex

FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.

  > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
  option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 47.337 secs

```
Command finished with error code 1: cmd /s /c "C:\Users\Gustavo\app\platfo
rms\android\gradlew.bat cdvBuildDebug -b C:\Users\Gustavo\app\platforms\an
droid\build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true -Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -Pand
roid.useDeprecatedNdk=true"
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
ERROR: In <declare-styleable> FontFamilyFont, unable to find attribute android:fontVariationSettings
ERROR: In <declare-styleable> FontFamilyFont, unable to find attribute android:ttcIndex


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
```

It's my first time posting here, so if I am doing something wrong, please tell me.

Comment: Might be the same problem as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49162538/5730444)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gustavo,

Its is possible that you have a conflict in cordova plugins or platform. A second possiblity is that, you have added components via npm but haven't installed it. For both scenario, I suggest that you list out the current versions installed, note them down then do an update to cordova. Here is how to list out the versions, like what I have.

`cd projectfolder
$ cordova plugin
cordova-plugin-console 1.1.0 "Console"
cordova-plugin-device 2.0.1 "Device"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.3 "Whitelist"
$ cordova platform
Installed platforms:
  android 7.0.0
  browser 5.0.3
Available platforms: 
  ios ~4.5.4
  osx ~4.0.1
  windows ~5.0.0
  www ^3.12.0
$ npm -v
3.10.10`

Here is how you update cordova for the project. This example assumes you are using android platform. If you have other plugins/platform, do the necessary.

```
npm install
npm update
cordova platform rm android --nosave
cordova platform add android
```

Alternatively

```
cordova platform update android
```

If you notice a specific plugin with version error, remove and the plugin with required version.

Comment: Thanks for the response!

I checked the versions, take a look:

C:\Users\Gustavo\app>cordova plugin
cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview 2.4.0 "Crosswalk WebView Engine"
cordova-plugin-media 5.0.2 "Media"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.2.2 "Whitelist"

C:\Users\Gustavo\app>cordova platform
Installed platforms:
  android 6.3.0
Available platforms:
  amazon-fireos ~3.6.3 (deprecated)
  blackberry10 ~3.8.0
  browser ~4.1.0
  firefoxos ~3.6.3
  webos ~3.7.0
  windows ~4.4.0
  wp8 ~3.8.2 (deprecated)

C:\Users\Gustavo\app>npm -v
5.7.1

Should I update something?

Comment: Try the 4 steps above. Start with npm install.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the help!

I got a build successful by adding this in the build-extras.gradle file:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
    }
}
```

And by installing the cordova-android-support-gradle-release.

Comment: Thats great. A general problem to be missing some required plugins or not installed.

Comment: this is a true answer.