# Ionic build android error : Failed to execute aapt

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework

I have some error and I don't know why the error is coming. I do not change anything and when I try to build android app it shows the error message

[image]

If somebody knows how to fix please tell me, thanks.

**EDIT**

more log details

[image]

Comment: Did you try this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49162538/running-cordova-build-android-unable-to-find-attribute-androidfontvariation

Comment: @UtkarshDubey I already tried but still error

Comment: Can you apply `--stacktrace`, `--info` or `--debug` to get more log details and you show that log here in question?

Comment: @UtkarshDubey I have updated question

Comment: Hi, Why not we chat somewhere else and try to fix your issue. I don't have enough privilege otherwise I will create a chat room here for discussion.