# AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found

Tags: cordova, mobile, moodle, cordova-android

> D:\wamp\www\moodle35>cordova build android
>       cordova-android-support-gradle-release: Android platform: V7.1.2+
>       cordova-android-support-gradle-release: Wrote custom version '27.1.0' to D:\wamp\www\moodle35\platforms\android\app\build.gradle
>       cordova-android-support-gradle-release: Wrote custom version '27.1.0' to D:\wamp\www\moodle35\platforms\android\app\src\main\cordova-android-su
>       port-gradle-release\properties.gradle
>       Android Studio project detected
>       cordova-android-support-gradle-release: Android platform: V7.1.2+
>       cordova-android-support-gradle-release: Wrote custom version '27.1.0' to D:\wamp\www\moodle35\platforms\android\app\build.gradle
>       cordova-android-support-gradle-release: Wrote custom version '27.1.0' to D:\wamp\www\moodle35\platforms\android\app\src\main\cordova-android-su
>       port-gradle-release\properties.gradle
>       ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\nageswararao.veerank.HSMUMSZ\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
>       JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181
>       studio
>       Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible Daemon could not be reused, use --status for details

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 15s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
publishNonDefault is deprecated and has no effect anymore. All variants are now published.
Configuration 'compile' in project ':app' is deprecated. Use 'implementation' instead.
The Task.leftShift(Closure) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use Task.doLast(Action) instead.
        at build_61485xmn41ihbiubsprvrv8vf.run(D:\wamp\www\moodle35\platforms\android\app\build.gradle:150)
:CordovaLib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugAidl
:CordovaLib:compileDebugRenderscript
:CordovaLib:checkDebugManifest
:CordovaLib:generateDebugBuildConfig
:CordovaLib:prepareLintJar
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResValues
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResources
:CordovaLib:packageDebugResources
:CordovaLib:platformAttrExtractor
:CordovaLib:processDebugManifest
:CordovaLib:javaPreCompileDebug
:CordovaLib:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild
:app:compileDebugAidl
:CordovaLib:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig
:app:prepareLintJar
:app:generateDebugResValues
:app:generateDebugResources
:app:mergeDebugResources
:app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests
:app:processDebugManifest
:app:splitsDiscoveryTaskDebug
:app:compileDebugNdk NO-SOURCE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugShaders
:CordovaLib:compileDebugShaders
:CordovaLib:generateDebugAssets
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugAssets
:app:mergeDebugShaders
:app:compileDebugShaders
:app:generateDebugAssets
:app:mergeDebugAssets
:CordovaLib:compileDebugNdk NO-SOURCE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugJniLibFolders
:CordovaLib:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug
:CordovaLib:transformNativeLibsWithIntermediateJniLibsForDebug
:app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders
:app:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
:app:validateSigningDebug
:CordovaLib:processDebugResources
:CordovaLib:generateDebugSources
:CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavacNote: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

:CordovaLib:transformClassesAndResourcesWithPrepareIntermediateJarsForDebug
:app:processDebugResourcesC:\Users\nageswararao.veerank.HSMUMSZ\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-compat-28.0.0.aar\f8e158bc4b211cbe50ec9
347737852a\res\values\values.xml:133:5-70: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.

C:\Users\nageswararao.veerank.HSMUMSZ\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-compat-28.0.0.aar\f8e158bc4b211cbe50ec9d347737852a\res\values\val
es.xml:133:5-70: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.

D:\wamp\www\moodle35\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:95: error: resource
android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
D:\wamp\www\moodle35\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:95: error: resource
android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
error: failed linking references.

Failed to execute aapt
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
        at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:796)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.invokeAaptForSplit(ProcessAndroidResources.java:551)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.doFullTaskAction(ProcessAndroidResources.java:285)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:109)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:173)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:121)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:122)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:111)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:63)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:124)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:80)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:105)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:625)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:580)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63) FAILED

        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: che
k logs for details
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:503)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:482)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:79)
        at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:794)
        ... 48 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:503)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:462)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:79)
        at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.QueueableAapt2.lambda$makeValidatedPackage$1(QueueableAapt2.java:179)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
        at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$NotifierProcessOutput.handleOutput(AaptProcess.java:463)
        at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$NotifierProcessOutput.err(AaptProcess.java:415)
        at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$ProcessOutputFacade.err(AaptProcess.java:332)
        at com.android.utils.GrabProcessOutput$1.run(GrabProcessOutput.java:104)

36 actionable tasks: 36 executed
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Failed to execute aapt

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 12s
cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
C:\Users\nageswararao.veerank.HSMUMSZ\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-compat-28.0.0.aar\f8e158bc4b211cbe50ec9d347737852a\res\values\val
es.xml:133:5-70: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.

C:\Users\nageswararao.veerank.HSMUMSZ\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-compat-28.0.0.aar\f8e158bc4b211cbe50ec9d347737852a\res\values\val
es.xml:133:5-70: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.

D:\wamp\www\moodle35\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:95: error: resource
android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
D:\wamp\www\moodle35\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:95: error: resource
android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
error: failed linking references.

Failed to execute aapt
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
        at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:796)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.invokeAaptForSplit(ProcessAndroidResources.java:551)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.doFullTaskAction(ProcessAndroidResources.java:285)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:109)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:173)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:121)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:122)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:111)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:63)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:124)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:80)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:105)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:625)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:580)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: che
k logs for details
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:503)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:482)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:79)
        at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:794)
        ... 48 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:503)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:462)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:79)
        at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.QueueableAapt2.lambda$makeValidatedPackage$1(QueueableAapt2.java:179)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
        at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$NotifierProcessOutput.handleOutput(AaptProcess.java:463)
        at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$NotifierProcessOutput.err(AaptProcess.java:415)
        at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$ProcessOutputFacade.err(AaptProcess.java:332)        at `enter code here`com.android.utils.GrabProcessOutput$1.run(GrabProcessOutput.java:104)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Failed to execute aapt

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 12s
```

Comment: Update the compile SDK to 28. These two are android attributes that were added in API 28, and some libraries (like support lib and app compat) versioned 28.0.0+ are using them.

Comment: does cordova-android support 28+ API?
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running "cordova build android" - unable to find attribute android:fontVariationSettings and android:ttcIndex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49162538/running-cordova-build-android-unable-to-find-attribute-androidfontvariation)

Answer (score 5):

**Solved**

I think this is the android version issue.

Run following command inside your projects

1. `ionic cordova platform rm android`
2. `ionic cordova platform add android@8.0.0`
3. `ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-androidx`
4. `ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter`

### Check also this configuration:

- Make sure your `gradle.properties` has:

`cdvMinSdkVersion=19`

- Make sure your build.gradle has:

```
project.ext { defaultBuildToolsVersion="28.0.3" //String

defaultMinSdkVersion=19 //Integer - Minimum requirement is Android 4.4 

defaultTargetSdkVersion=28 //Integer - We ALWAYS target the latest by default 

defaultCompileSdkVersion=28 //Integer - We ALWAYS compile with the latest by default }
```

- Make sure your confix.xml has:

`preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19"`