# keep getting "Error:in <declare-styleable> unable to find attribute android:font" android leanback

Tags: java, android, android-tv, leanback

[image]

App gradle.

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


    android {

            compileSdkVersion 24
            buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

            defaultConfig {
                     applicationId "tv.xx.xxx.xxxxxxxxx"
                     minSdkVersion 21
                     targetSdkVersion 24
                     multiDexEnabled true
            }

            dependencies {
                     compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
                     compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.0.0'
                     compile 'com.android.support:leanback-v17:24.0.0'
            }
    }
```

Build gradle..

```
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
            maven {
                url 'https://maven.google.com/'
                name 'Google'
            }
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        }
    }
```

I opened this project and Android studio after about 1 year, when initializing the project there was an error called

> " failed to resolve com.android.support:support-media-compact:27.0.0 "

after adding 
        `maven {
                url 'https://maven.google.com/'
                name 'Google'
        }` that problem was solved. after that I
keep getting that error, I tried changing versions but didn't work. Tried few solutions in here nothing is worked so far.

Comment: post your xml file with that `<declare-styleable>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running "cordova build android" - unable to find attribute android:fontVariationSettings and android:ttcIndex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49162538/running-cordova-build-android-unable-to-find-attribute-androidfontvariation)

Comment: @pskink actually those files are from leanback library. In my project xml files doesn't contain `<declare-styleable>` tag..